# nginx rewrite ruining query string

Tags: nginx

so i have an nginx rewrite where i add basically make everything coming in go though http

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name website.com api.website.com;
        rewrite ^ http://www.website.com$request_uri permanent;
}
```

if i pass in

api.website.com/rest/v1.0/search?keyword=block

my querystring parameter gets mangled and the url turns into:

http://www.website.com/rest/v1.0/search?keyword=block%3Fkeyword%3Dblock

why is it doing this and how do i make it stop?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name website.com api.website.com;
        rewrite ^ http://www.website.com permanent;
}
```

kill the request_uri?